# Control multiple LEDs using an IC and PC/Linux thru USB

Tags: microcontroller, usb, integrated-circuit, programming

I've already tried to search this topic but all Google results said that this isn't possible. Is there any chance of controlling multiple LEDs using a PC/Linux, through USB? The diagram might look like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR1Lq.png]

This is just a made up circuit I created. Resistors, capacitors, Inductors, or any other components might be included in the real product.

In detail, an application is able to send data to the IC, and the IC in turn will turn on the LED. In the application, the user can choose which of the LEDs are turned on and off.

What IC or ICs do I need to use to receive data from the computer via USB? And what programming language do I need to use to control the IC? Or what other components do I need to use to make this possible?

***PS:
IT is more like a Raspberry Pi controlling LEDs to turn on and off thru its header pins. But in this mattter, USB will be the mode of connection and I will be the one who will create the circuit(and the application).

Comment: See e.g. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/267/id-like-to-learn-how-to-make-my-own-usb-gadgets?rq=1 or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35184/c-c-c-programming-for-interfacing-usb-to-pic-microcontroller?rq=1 : this is a popular sort of question here.

Answer (score 2):

How bout this:

Use the FT245RL, which is available on a breakout board here:

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/7841

To code for this chip, modify one of the software examples here:

http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples.htm

However, this chip cannot supply a lot of current. It could be used instead to turn on something like a 2N7000 to switch on the LED. Note you will need a resistor in series with the LED to limit the current supplied.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy way for interaction with USB and PC will be pic controller with usb firmware install. Its also provide lot feature.

```
http://www.instructables.com/id/USB-Project-USB-Interface-Board-Using-PIC18F455/
```

Event though its quite costlier then other components, But its multi purpose one.